# Ant and Junit: no xml report being generated

Tags: ant, junit, teamcity, sikuli

I'm very new to ant and junit.  I need junit to create an xml output so I can integrate with team city.  The tests run just fine, but I'm not getting any output in the directory that I'm specifying.  I'm running on windows 7.  I have junit.jar and ant-junit.jar in my ant_home/lib directory.  here is my build xml target:

```
<target name="onlyjunit-sikuli" description="Execute All sikuli tests">
    <delete dir="${automated}/results/sikuli"/>
    <mkdir dir="${automated}/results"/>
    <mkdir dir="${automated}/results/sikuli"/>
    <junit printsummary="yes" showoutput="yes" fork="true" forkmode="once">
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Xms512m"/>
        <jvmarg value="-Dsikuli.mode=${sikuli.mode}"/>
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
       <formatter type="xml"/>
       <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
        <batchtest if="env.testname" todir="${automated}/results/sikuli">
            <fileset dir="${automated}/src">
                <include name="**/com/foo/builder/Sikuli/**/${env.testname}.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <test unless="env.testname"  name="com.foo.builder.Sikuli.SikuliTestSuite"/>
    </junit>
   <junitreport todir="${automated}/results/sikuli/report">
        <fileset dir="${automated}/results/sikuli" includes="*.xml"/>
        <report todir="${automated}/results/sikuli/report"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you missing a `todir` in your `test` element?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a todir on the test element.