# Jenkins build fail due to Junit test report not found : Intern Framework

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, intern

My jenkins version is 1.608 and JUnit plugin is 1.2beta 4. When I run the test locally I can see that the reports are correctly generated but when I run the build it fails [also I dont see the reports in the folder]. 
The folder structure looks like `workspace/java/src/proj/test/test1/*.xml.`
Not sure what the problem is. This was fine until last week. The jenkins configurations also gives shows an error in the Publish Junit test report section `‘src\proj\test\test1\report.xml’ doesn’t match anything: ‘src’ exists but not ‘src\proj\test\test1\report.xml’`

Error-

```
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Recording test results
    ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver aborted due to exception
    hudson.AbortException: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
        at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:116)
        at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:92)
        at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2688)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
        at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:325)
        at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:69)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)
        at ......remote call to tm1w08perf11-5000(Native Method)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1360)
        at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:221)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:753)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:978)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
        at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser.parseResult(JUnitParser.java:89)
        at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parse(JUnitResultArchiver.java:121)
        at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:138)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:74)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
```

Comment: You need to add more information. Buildsystem, verbose build log, jenkins configuration.

Comment: How do you run tests? Using Ant? Then how do you define target folder for reports? Something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994790/ant-and-junit-no-xml-report-being-generated ?

Comment: So these are intern tests and they run as a separate project on a separate  jenkins (slave) machine.

Comment: This is my Test Report XMLs Path: **/abc/test/target/surefire-reports/*.xml      This is my local path /Users/ddigges/dev/abc/trunk/src/qbo/test/target/surefire-reports                  Also, Jenkins version: Jenkins ver. 1.609.1.1 (CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise 15.05)

Comment: Based on your local path ` /Users/ddigges/...` I guess Jenkins is running on a Linux host. The error messages states a build step `Execute Windows batch command`. Do you try to run a Windows batch script on a Linux machine?

Comment: @deborah-digges @SubOptimal `/Users/ddigges` is likely OS X

Comment: This is the exact message I'm getting: Recording test results
01:22:01 ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver aborted due to exception
01:22:01 hudson.AbortException: No test report files were found. Configuration error?

Comment: So, are you using windows as jenkins node? If so, put either double backslash in configuration, or simple slash, to comply all systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will help you but this worked fine for me when I encountered the same issue:

[No test report files were found in Hudson with NUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089602/no-test-report-files-were-found-in-hudson-with-nunit)

What you need to do to fix this: Place the *.xml-folder in the workspace-folder of Hudson and modify "Publish NUnit test result report" in a way that only the name of your *.xml-folder is given, not the absolute path.